# Is there a way to use ntlm authentication when using the RESTinstance library in robotframework

Tags: robotframework, python-requests-html

I would like to use the `RESTInstance` library - https://github.com/asyrjasalo/RESTinstance with ntlm authentication

I have tried various setup by using the `auth` setting for the `GET command`

This is what my code looks like but fails `authorization` on the server

```
@{auth}=  Create List  user pass
  create ntlm session  SIT  api/enpoint  auth=@{auth}
  REST.GET         api/endpoint  auth=${auth}
```

I get an `unauthorized` error message